# Can I add a custom object similar to quotes to opportunities?

Tags: administration

I would like to add an object to opportunities that allows users to generate a Method Statement relating to a specific opportunity.

Essentially, I want to add fields from the opportunity to one of a choice of templates, create a pdf and email to a customer / contact.

The body of the template would have to be capable accepting a number of pages of text, preformatted, nothing to be updated from salesforce.

This is currently done manually using word....

Is it possible to copy the quote object and make changes?

This maybe a basic request, but my expertise in salesforce is limited, but growing slowly!!

Any advice, greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Fin

Comment: Do you need an object? You might consider an option like Conga or Drawloop to generate your PDF, attach and deliver an email quote via an email.

Comment: Many thanks Greenstork for your reply....yes, I will check out this option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the opportunity concerned, view the section Activty History. You will find a button, mail merge. This will allow you to select a Word document template into which the opportunity information (and optionally contact information) is merged. You can select the template to use. This should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for Response, was looking at this option. Maybe the most straight forward way of doing it. I was probably over complicating the whole thing!!